# Meteor - Get a Session value into input value in template

Tags: templates, meteor

I have a helper template that changes the appearance of an input field when it's the selected item in another template. What I now want to do is use that same template to either tell that input field it is not selected or pass a Session value if it is.

Here is the template:

```
<template name="income">
{{#each accounts}}
<tr>
  <td class="row1"><input type="text" maxlength="58" value="{{income_acct_name}}" id="income_acct_name{{_id}}"></td>
  {{#if selectedAcct }}
     <td class="row4" align="right"><input type="text" size="13" value="{{amount}}" id="income_amt_entered{{_id}}" class="open" readonly></td>
  {{else}}
    <td class="row4" align="right"><input type="text" size="13" value="" id="income_amt_entered{{_id}}" disabled></td>
  {{/if}}
  <td class="row5" align="right">{{formatMoney income_acct_total}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Here is the helper:

```
Template.income.selectedAcct= function(){
var amount = "";
var selectedAcct = Session.get('selectedAcct');
var thisAcct = "income_amt_entered" + this._id;
if (thisAcct == selectedAcct)
{
    return {amount: Session.get('amount')};
} else {
    return false;
}
};
```

I tried to wrap `{{#with selectedAcct}}` where I try to insert `{{amount}}` but ever other helper for this template started throwing errors because they can no longer see the id of that input element-

```
    {{#with selectedAcct}}
     <td class="row4" align="right"><input type="text" size="13" value="{{amount}}" id="income_amt_entered{{_id}}" class="open" readonly></td>
    {{/with}}

TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
```

Is there a way to pass that value from `Template.income.selectedAcct` or do I need to go a different way?

Comment: Just use `{{selectedAcct.amount}}`.

Comment: LOL! Thanks Rich for bringing me back down to Earth. Sometimes I over complicate things.

Comment: No probs, glad it was an easy one!